# react-hook-form material-ui (FormControlLabel + Checkbox) using Controller

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

to use Material-ui in react-hook-form you should use <Controller and the method render instead of "as = {xy-control}" Also should not mix controller and inputRef = {register}.
A single control is also no problem.
But there is a compound control in Material-ui. "FormControlLabel + CheckBox" how do you integrate this control in the controller. All my attempts have failed.

This is how it works but I would like the FormControlLaben to be enclosed by the controller.
Does somebody has any idea?

```
                 <Controller
                    name="password"
                    control={control}
                    defaultValue={""}
                    render={(props) => <TextField {...props}
                                                  variant="outlined"
                                                  margin="normal"
                                                  required
                                                  fullWidth
                                                  label="Password"
                                                  type="password"
                                                  id="password"
                                                  autoComplete="current-password"
                    />}
                />

                <FormControlLabel
                    control={
                        <Checkbox
                            inputRef={register}
                            name="remember"
                        />
                    }
                    label="remember"
                />


{/*That works, but it requires an OnChange. Why can't the controller bind it?*/}
                <FormControlLabel
                    control={
                        <Controller
                            name={"remember2"}
                            control={control}
                            render={(props) => (
                                <Checkbox
                                    {...props}
                                    onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.checked)}

                                />
                            )}
                        />
                    }
                    label="remember"
                />
```

Answer (score 6):

this was enough for me w/ Mui 5 & RHF 7

```
const { watch, register } = useForm<{saveEmail: boolean}>({
  defaultValues: { saveEmail: true },
});

...

<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Checkbox {...register('saveEmail')} checked={watch('saveEmail')} />
  }
  label="save email"
/>
```

Comment: Using watch worked perfectly ty. I most upvoted answer didn't work for me. I don't need to use `Controller` with your answer eacher. Much simpler!

Comment: Nice this also works for select to get rid of the controller tag

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it

```
<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Controller
      control={control}
      inputRef={register}
      name='controlName'
      render={({onChange, value}) => (
        <Checkbox
          onChange={e => onChange(e.target.checked)}
          checked={value}
        />
      )}
    />
  }
  label="This is a label"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

From v7, I used this :

```js
    <Controller
        name='contactAutre'
        control={control}
        defaultValue={false}
        render={({ field }) => (
            <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox {...field} />}
                label='Autre'
            />
        )}
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to make things more controlled:

```js
<FormControlLabel
label="label here"
control={
    <Controller
    name="isSeparatedDelivery"
    control={control}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
        <Checkbox
        checked={value}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.checked)}
        />
    )}
    />
}
/>
```

or

```js
<Controller
control={control}
name="selected"
render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
  <FormControlLabel
    control={
      <Checkbox
        label="Sélectionner la question"
        checked={value}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    }
    label="Sélectionner la question"
  />
)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [Leo Roese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nt8NTuUbuG4&t=1169s&ab_channel=LeoRoese) for his example for `Textfield`. However you can apply the same logic for Checkboxes but slightly tweak.

```js
const { control, formState: { errors } } = useForm()

<Controller
    name="privacyAccept"
    control={control}
    render={({ field }) => (
    <>
        <FormControlLabel
        control={<Checkbox {...field} />}
        label="I agree to the privacy policy"
        />
        {errors.privacyAccept && (
        <FormHelperText error>{errors.privacyAccept.message}</FormHelperText>
        )}
    </>
    )}
/>
```